# Wocommerce custom field length must be 15 numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an optional custom field billing_vat. I want to have that field length to 15 no less or more.

I added the code below but my website keeps crashing from time to time

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'vat_validation_numbers' );
   
function vat_validation_numbers() { 
   if ( isset( $_POST['billing_vat'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['billing_vat'] ) ) {
      if ( strlen( $_POST['billing_vat'] ) == 15 ) {
         wc_add_notice( 'VAT must be 15 Numbers', 'error' );
      }
   }   
}
```

and to implement the 15 lengths in the user billing address I added the hook ***"woocommerce_billing_fields"*** which seems it doesn't work on the billing address in the user account page because all the billing fields disappeared.

How can I force that field to be 15 in length if someone fills a number inside it in both the checkout and user address billing page?

Comment: Crashing from time to time is another level of coding. Please share your code not only validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `jQuery`, for example,

```
var billingVat = $.trim($('#billing_vat').val());

if (billingVat.length != 15) {
   $('#billing_vat').css('backgroundColor', '#fcf6d5');
   alert("Please enter numeric 15 digit billing vat code above.");
   return false;
}
```